# Linear Algebra - Matrix, Ax=b

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to confirm my way of proof for this question:

Let $b \in R^{n}$. If $A$ and $B$ are row equivalent and $Ax=b$ has a solution, then $Bx=b$ also has a solution.

If I understand it correctly, for the same $b$, if I make row adjustment from $A$ to $B$, there is no guarantee that I will find a  $x$ such that $Bx=b$.

So I would like to find a counter-example to disprove the question.

Which way should I start looking at?

Should I just write some random row-equivalent Matrices?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Consider $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$.  Are these row-equivalent?

Comment: "*Should I just write some* **random** *row-equivalent matrices?*"  No.  You should however try some arbitrarily selected ones like the ones I suggest, picking the examples such that arithmetic is incredibly easy to perform.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much! I will try it now.